# Users unable to access group folder

Tags: permissions, groups

I have a folder in an AD login environment:

```
drwxrwx---   4 tbest3       cri-meltzer_anemia         102 Jul 11 11:06 Anemia
drwxrwx---   4 339776130 339820461   102 Jul 11 11:06 Anemia
```

These two users can cd the folder, e.g.,

```
# id tbest3 | tr "," "\n" | grep anemia
788681882(cri-meltzer_anemia_dir)
339820998(cri-meltzer_anemia_s)
339820461(cri-meltzer_anemia)

# id mprochas | tr "," "\n" | grep anemia
339820461(cri-meltzer_anemia)
788681882(cri-meltzer_anemia_dir)
339820998(cri-meltzer_anemia_s)
```

However, this user can't even though they have appropriate group permissions:

```
# id dmeltzer | tr "," "\n" | grep anemia
339820998(cri-meltzer_anemia_s)
339820461(cri-meltzer_anemia)
788681882(cri-meltzer_anemia_dir)
```

The only way I can get the user to access the folder is by setting the folder's other permissions to executable:

```
# chmod o+x Anemia
```

So my assumption is that the user is not being recognized as apart of group. I can't figure out why, as the the diagnostics information is quiet limited and all the user / group ids look appropriate.

```
# getfacl Anemia
# file: Anemia
# owner: tbest3
# group: cri-meltzer_anemia
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---

# file Anemia
Anemia: directory
```

Any ideas how I should about troubleshooting this?

M